# Closed formula for a homogeneous second order linear ODE

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

Let $A, B, C\geq 0$ be constants. Is there an explicit formula to a nontrivial solution to the homogeneous linear ODE
$$y''(t) -(A+B\,\sin t)\,y'(t) -C\, y(t)=0$$
for $t\in(0,2\pi)$ with periodic boundary condition $y(0)=y(2\pi)$?

p.s. This equation does not seem to be taken cared of in any "Handbook of differential equation". Please correct me if this statement is wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Presumably you don't want the solution  $y(t) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

For $A=0$, Maple finds a solution:

$$ y(t) = {\it HeunC} \left( 2\,B,-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},-B,C+\frac{3}{8}+\frac{B}{2},\frac{\cos(t)+1}{2} \right) $$